# c++ packet merge username between byte problem

Tags: c++, send, packet, recv

I'm tired due to this problem. I have tried everything to do this basic thing but have not been successful!

This is what I am trying to do:

```cpp
unsigned char info[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x68, 0x69, 0x04 };
send(my_socket, (char*)info, sizeof(info), 0);
```

Everything here is working fine as you can see

```cpp
0x68 0x69 = hi
```

I'm trying to do custom string between (0x1,0x2,0x3) and (0x4)
so it should be like:

```cpp
// whatever length !
unsigned char USERNAME[] = { 0x68, 0x69, 0x68, 0x69, 0x68, 0x69 }
// I want merge username between the packets !
unsigned char info[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, USERNAME, 0x04 };
```

anyone please?

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking how to write code to insert the username in between?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing great, you have done right as you are trying to merge the username between the data and send it using socket.
You have to use the little tweak,

Because `info` and `USERNAME` are `const size array` you can not directly insert one into another, first create an array of the size of the length of both the arrays. 
Then, wherever you want just define the position. You should create a separate function to merge this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){

    unsigned char USERNAME[] = {0x68, 0x69, 0x68, 0x69, 0x68, 0x69};
    unsigned char info[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04};

    int usernameSize = *(&USERNAME + 1) - USERNAME;
    int infoSize = *(&info + 1) - info;
    int totalSize = usernameSize + infoSize;

    unsigned char mergedInfo[totalSize]; 

    int pos = infoSize - 2; // whatever position you want 
    int i=0; // iterator

    while(i < totalSize){
        if(i < pos){
            mergedInfo[i] = info[i];
        }else if(i < (pos + usernameSize)){
            mergedInfo[i] = USERNAME[i-pos];
        }else{
            cout << " i " <<i-(usernameSize) << endl;
            mergedInfo[i] = info[i-usernameSize];
        }
        i++;
    }

    // debugging -> to check
    for(auto const& i:mergedInfo){
        cout << static_cast<int>(i) << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Happy coding ;-)